# How to do command Line parsing in C# with operation verbs?

Tags: .net, console, console-application

I have to implement a C# console application which performs various operations taking in parameters.

```
mytool.exe operationverb --param1 value1 --param2 value2
```

Is there a command line parser which can do this. I have tried utilities like NDesk.Options, where I can do

```
mytool.exe --operation operationverb --param1 value1 --param2 value2
```

I don't want users to do "--operation". What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The [Command Line Parser Library](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) lets you define a syntax similar to git or other popular command line tools.

yourapp verb1 --opt-1 --opt-2

Hope this helps.